# How to get all chat members of Telegram group?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Using Pyrogram I am trying to get the id of users who are chat members, but the `get_chat_members` function does not return all users, about 5-10 depending on the selected group, although there are many more in the chat. How do I get all users?

```py
from pyrogram import Client

# Target supergroup
TARGET = "id"

app = Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

async def main():
    async with app:
        async for member in app.get_chat_members(TARGET):
            print(member.user.id)


app.run(main())
```

I tried to use the `iter_chat_members` method from an older version of pyrogram, but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You might need to remove any `limit`:

```
async def main():
   async with Client("anon", api_id, api_hash) as app:
        async for member in app.get_chat_members(TARGET, limit=0):
            print(member.user.id)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I tried to use any limits as 0, 50, 200 but it doesn't help

Comment: I've just tested your code an I get all the members ID back as expected; about 72 id's for my chat.

Comment: I try to get ids from group with 238 members but I get only 3 id. Maybe it is because I'm not administrator of this group?

Comment: I'm also not a admin, there must be something else going on. Not sure what tho, maybe add a sleeper to make sure your not spamming Telegram

Comment: I have three different groups on my account. For a group with 238 members, I get all their id, for a group with 515 only 3, and for 1849 only 10